# Display two block elements on same line using CSS

Tags: php, html, css

So I'm trying to print this out on one line, But when it executes it prints the statement out on two separate lines. Any ideas why? 
Example: 
Welcome
12/14/2012

`<?php
 print("<h1>Welcome</h1>" .
    "<h2>" . Date('n \/ j \/ Y') . "</h2>"); 
 ?>`

If this make any difference I'm trying to print a welcome one the left side of the page, and the date on the right Example:
Welcome             12/14/2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that's an html issue. As h1 and h2 are block level elements the browser puts a line break at the end. You can use css to change that or use more appropriate html

```
<?php print("<h1 style='display:inline;'>Welcome</h1>" . "<h2 style='display:inline;'>" . Date('n \/ j \/ Y') . "</h2>"); ?>
```

Comment: Thats what I figured, but I wasn't sure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php print("<h1>Welcome  " . Date('n \/ j \/ Y') )."</h1>"; ?>
```

Comment: Why was it downvoted? Perfectly valid answer for the question, +1

Comment: Perfectly good answer, only thing I would change is to wrap the date in a span so further styles can be applied.

Comment: @zerkms you didn't see it before the edit. I have reversed my down vote

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. But unfortunately I would like to use a h1 and and h2.

Comment: @mvmrocks: "But unfortunately I would like to use a h1 and and h2" --- that's why it really matters **how** you ask a question :)

Comment: The question was to have the `<h1>` on the left and `<h2>` on the right; this has both on the left.

Comment: @Jack: with the code from answer you would have the `Welcome` from the left of the date. And there is nothing about keeping `h1` and `h2`. So it's not ideal, but it fits requirements :-)

Comment: @zerkms Yes, but technically they'd still be on the same *side* of the page.

Comment: @mvmrocks -- Did u tried with this..? previously its an hmtl cause.

Answer (score 0):

**Also a tip:**
Think in boxes and find out which elements are blockelements.
If they are block-elements you have to float them OR change them into Inline-Objects.